# for loop insert query turn into update query in transaction function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

i check my query .It insert 1st loop after that insert query turn into update is there anyway how to fix this

```
$database = New database;
DB::transaction(function () use ($database) {
         for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
           database->save();
         }
       });
```

here is my transaction picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `$database = New database;` inside the `for` statement. Because in each loop you need a new database object to do the insertion. Currently, you make an object, then the first loop does the insertion and the reset of loops will update the same object.